# powershell mandatory parameter with default value shown

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am looking for a way to have an PowerShell script ask for an parameter which needs to be mandatory, but shown with an default value, e.g.:

```
    .\psscript
    Supply values for the following parameters:
    parameter1[default value]:
    parameter2[1234]:
```

I want to ask for input but provide some default values.

If I use the mandatory option it asks for the values nicely but doesn't show the default value or process the given value.  If I don't make it mandatory then PowerShell doesn't ask for the value at all.

Here's some script examples I tried:

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SqlServiceAccount = $env:computername + "_sa",
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SqlServiceAccountPwd
    )
```

This script asks for parameters but does not show or process the default value if I just press enter on the first parameter.

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] $SqlServiceAccount = $env:computername + "_sa",
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SqlServiceAccountPwd
    )
```

This script doesn't ask for the first parameter, but processes the default value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a *short* example that might help:

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        $SqlServiceAccount = (Read-Host -prompt "SqlServiceAccount ($($env:computername + "_sa"))"),
        $SqlServiceAccountPwd = (Read-Host -prompt "SqlServiceAccountPwd")
    )
    if (!$SqlServiceAccount) { $SqlServiceAccount = $env:Computername + "_sa" }
    ...
```

Comment: Read-Host is almost always wrong, as it depends on the host in which the script is being run and stops execution at that point. This will not work in logon scripts, or any other location where your script will gets called from a non-interactive host.

Answer (score 8):

By definition: mandatory parameters don't have default values. Even if you provide one, PowerShell will prompt for value unless specified when the command is called. There is however a 'hacky' way to get what you ask for. As variables (and as consequence - parameters) can have any name you wish, it's enough to define command with parameters that match the prompt you would like to see:

```
function foo {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Alias('Parameter1')]
        [AllowNull()]
        ${Parameter1[default value]},
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Alias('Parameter2')]
        [AllowNull()]
        ${Parameter2[1234]}
    )
    $Parameter1 = 
        if (${Parameter1[default value]}) {
            ${Parameter1[default value]}
        } else {
            'default value'
        }
    $Parameter2 = 
        if (${Parameter2[1234]}) {
            ${Parameter2[1234]}
        } else {
            1234
        }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Parameter1 = $Parameter1
        Parameter2 = $Parameter2
    }
}
```

When called w/o parameters, function will present user with prompt that match parameter names. When called with `-Parameter1 notDefaultValue` and/or with `-Parameter2 7`, aliases will kick in and assign passed value to the selected parameter. As variables named like that are no fun to work with - it makes sense to assign value (default or passed by the user) to variable that matches our alias/ fake parameter name.

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it this way

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$aString
)

if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($aString))
{
   $aString = "A Default Value"
}
```

In my opinion, if you're using `Read-Host` in a `param()` block, then you're doing something wrong. At that point, what's the point of using `param()` at all?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to do what you want with a mandatory parameter and powershell prompting for you.

You would instead have to make it optional (remove mandatory), then implement the prompting code yourself (`Read-Host`, but take blank response as a default; something like that).