# How to output the referenced value?

Tags: powershell

I have the following function.

```
function Params {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Alias('Param1')]
        [AllowNull()]
        ${Param1[default value]}
    )
    [ref] $Param1 = 
        if (${Param1[default value]}) {
            ${Param1[default value]}
        } else {
            'default'
        }
}

Params

$input1 = $null

"the param input is $([ref]$input1)"
```

If i input something for parameter on prompt or if i leave it to default value, i get this as output for `$([ref]$input)`

> the param input is System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives+Null]

Why am i not getting a value instead?

I want this output for example:

> the param input is default

Comment: the word `$Input` is a reserved word and should NOT be used for anything other than _reading from it_.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for pointing that out; ok, i used a different word. i am still getting same error

Comment: this line `${Param1[default value]}` creates a variable named `Param1[default value]` - which makes no sense. [*grin*] ///// what is your goal? this code is ... strange and nearly meaningless to me ... [*blush*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey the function i used is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39880424/8397835

Comment: @Lee_Dailey essentially im just trying to build on that function by having a nice output of whatever value the Param1 is set to. i looked up and it said you eithe rhave to call the function in the scope or use reference as i did here. using ref is much more like it in my case so i went with it

Comment: the answer by BartekB that you have ... mangled ... is bizarre. it _works_ but does so quite strangely. if you really want to use a convoluted, obscure, not-QUITE-insane bit  of code, then stick with what he showed. if you want reasonable, fairly direct, far-from-insane code ... use the accepted answer. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey unfortunately i would have to define that at the beginning of script otherwise i would get Unexpected attribute 'CmdletBinding'.

Comment: that is a SHORT snippet - not an entire function. [*grin*] simply wrap it in the normal function definition to make it work in your script.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey but then i would still need to use Reference to accomplish what i am trying to do...are you saying the accepted answer will work with ref? in any case, i defined it at the beginning without function and the cmdletbinding works just fine, so i guess its suiting my purposes already

Comment: don't use `[ref]` unless you have a NEED for it. i can't see any need - and don't see any way to make it work with the code provided.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey the need would be lets say if i used param in a function, and lets say i wanna pass that param variable later in the script to an output sentence, like my post

Comment: i am sorry, but i can't think of any reason to do it that way. [*blush*]  it seems like a waste of time and effort to achieve something that can be done directly instead of in a convoluted, obscure, difficult-to-understand method.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey its cool, i found a way around it :). thanks for your suggestions so far!

Comment: neato! please, would you post the solution? i am oh-so-curious ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i posted an answer :) would appreciate an upvote ^_^

Comment: thank you for posting it! [*grin*] ///// i upvoted it - not because it answered your original question, but because it answered your _intent_ that drove you to the original question. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thank you for your guidance

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resorting to a different method to achieve what i want:

Defining this at the top of script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    $Param1 = (Read-Host -prompt "Param1")
)
if (!$Param1) { "default" }

"the param input is $Param1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[ref]` type accelerator (it's not a type accelerator in the usual sense, but it *does* create PSReference objects, so... it sort of is) gets you, as it tells you, a PSReference object.

In order to retrieve the value from it, you'd need to ask for it specifically. In your code, you can access it by pulling the `Value` property from the created reference object.

```
"the param input is $(([ref]$input1).Value)"
```

However, given that `$input1` isn't assigned to, you might have to refactor a bit to get what you're after.

Comment: Interesting, ima have to try this tomorrow!